# App don't install on iOS in Codename One

Tags: ios, certificate, code-signing, codenameone

I configured my project for signing by developer certificate. This sertificate was tested with phonegap builds, therefore there is reason to believe that it is correct.

I also read http://www.codenameone.com/signing.html, but it could not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you go over all the steps here: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-code-signing-fail-checklist

Make sure the P12 file has a password.

Make sure the package name of the main project matches the APP ID and that the app ID value is correct.

Comment: Yep. Package name don't match with APP ID. I fixed this, but did not help. Package name: eu.indevgroup.cn1.app; APP ID: Q5GHSKAL2F.eu.indevgroup.cn1.app

Comment: It is strange that after APP ID fixing, the app size increased from  28.6 mb to 87.4 mb

Comment: I'm guessing this might be related to the new VM. Its possible the 64bit and additional screenshots are triggering this see http://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-codename-one-ios-vm-is-now-the-default

Comment: This option (ios.newVM=false) reduces the file size, but it still do not install

Comment: The app id you are using is incorrect, the prefix should be the one used in your account matching your provisioning profile from Apple.